# Eclipse dark color theme fixes

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, fonts, color-scheme

I've finaly decided to fix the twitches with Eclipse dark color theme. I am using [Moonrise theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme#.U5qcbfl_tqI) and I couldn't find any options to fix them via Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts.

The first annoying twitch is with content assist window, where I can not see which entry is chosen. There is slightly different background for selected entry, but it's barely visible:

[image]

The second problem is with the menu entries color which is black when selected, making it really hard to read:

[image]

Have anyone tried to solve this problems and how?

Comment: You might want to look at Eclipse Luna (4.4) which is now on Release Candidate 4 and will be released this month. Luna has a built in dark theme.

Comment: Actually, this is LPCXpresso IDE for embedded development, built on top of Eclipse, so I can't just use the latest Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

```
Preferences > Appearance > Colors and Fonts

Basic > Content Assist Background Color
Basic > Content Assist Foreground Color
Basic > Counter Color
```

[My Preferences Settings for Content Assist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6396b.png)

another problem may turn up with the color of hyperlinks, like those in the menu or in the hover-popup on errors.
see: [Hyperlinkcolor in a dark theme unreadable under win 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435828/hyperlinkcolor-in-dark-theme-unreadable-under-win-10) (currently unsolved)