# Hyperlinkcolor in a dark theme unreadable under win 10

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, hyperlink, color-scheme

I´m using a dark theme in eclipse (moonrise).
In this theme hyperlinks in the native windows 10 color are not readable against dark gray or black background. (I need a solution for Java)

(if you don´t know what a hyperlink is: under Preferences > General > Content Types  "File Associations" is a hyperlink; hyperlinks also show up in a pop up, when you hover over errors in your code, all the suggestions are hyperlinks and appear in the same color)

Ive tried Preferences > Appearence > Colors and Fonts, Preferences > Editors > Text Editors, Preferences > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations
and everything under Preferences > Java.
It didn`t solve the problem.

It seems to be a system-wide setting and enabling high-contrast mode solves the problem, but I don´t want to use high contrast mode, because I think it has less contrast than normal and it´s ugly.

Under Windows 7 you could change it under Control Panel > Personalization > Advanced. But as of Windows 8, this option is no longer available.

I wan´t to know how I can change the color of hyperlinks without enabling high-contrast mode in windows 10.

---

other problems with Moonrise are discussed there:
[Eclipse dark color theme fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199237/eclipse-dark-color-theme-fixes/39435952#39435952)

Comment: The moonrise theme isn't the official Eclipse dark theme. Did you try the default one, with the latest version of Eclipse IDE?

Comment: I did, but I don't like it